# STM32L-Discovery EXTI Interrupt fail

Tags: c, embedded, interrupt, stm32ldiscovery

working on STM32L151xx on IAR compiler.

I am trying getting EXTI interrupt but getting nowhere, here is my code which is basically direct from sample codes but not working,

```
  EXTI_InitTypeDef EXTI_InitStructure;
  NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_10;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);
  RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_SYSCFG, ENABLE);
  SYSCFG_EXTILineConfig(EXTI_PortSourceGPIOA, EXTI_PinSource10);
  EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_Line = EXTI_Line1;
  EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_Mode = EXTI_Mode_Interrupt;
  EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_Trigger = EXTI_Trigger_Rising_Falling;  
  EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_LineCmd = ENABLE;
  EXTI_Init(&EXTI_InitStructure);
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = EXTI1_IRQn;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 1;//0x0F;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 1;//0x0F;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
  NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);
  EXTI_GenerateSWInterrupt(EXTI_Line1);
```

When I HIGH the PA10 pin, I get no software interrupt, The code does not goes to `EXTI1_IRQHandler()`, What seems to be missing?
**Edit**
On `EXTI_GetFlagStatus` I am getting 0
and `EXTI_GETITStatus` I am getting 0

Comment: I would start the peripheral clock *before* writing its registers, you could try that.

Comment: @unwind SOLVED: PA9 is connected to Line9, and PA10 Line 10

The interrupt service via EXTI9_5_IRQHandler (EXTI9_5_IRQn), and EXTI15_10_IRQHandler (EXTI15_10_IRQn)

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer so that you can eventually accept it to resolve the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PA9` is connected to `Line9`, and `PA10` `Line 10` The interrupt service via `EXTI9_5_IRQHandler (EXTI9_5_IRQn)`, and `EXTI15_10_IRQHandler (EXTI15_10_IRQn)`

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit more? The only verb in your sentence is "is connected"...